# Parameter set in Wagtail block not appearing in admin UI

Tags: wagtail

I created a custom block class that inherits from Wagtail's URL Block. When initializing the URL Block within this class, I set the help_text parameter. The custom block displays correctly, aside from the fact that the help text doesn't show. It's not present in the UI when the block loads, and hovering over the block doesn't show the help text either. The documentation notes that this help_text parameter is available for URL Blocks. Where should the help text be, and how can I get it to show in my custom block?

I'm using Wagtail version 4.1.1

Code snippet of the custom block:

```
class AirtableBlock(URLBlock):
    url = URLBlock(icon="link", help_text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")

    class Meta:
        template = "core/blocks/airtable_embed.html"
        icon = "code"
```

Screenshot:
[Custom block in admin UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKHsZ.png)

I've tried adding the help_text parameter to the URL Block. I expect to see the text added to the UI, but it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constructing custom blocks, you need to inherit StructBlock.
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html

The form rendering will take care of the help text then:

```
class AirtableBlock(StructBlock):
    url = URLBlock(icon="link", help_text="url help")

    class Meta:
        template = "core/blocks/airtable_embed.html"
        icon = "code"
```

Then in your StreamField:

```
    content = StreamField(
        [
            ...,
            ("url", AirtableBlock(help_text="Block level help"))
        ],
```

This will render with:

[image]